# Password protected / private repositories?

Tags: ppa

Is it possible to create a have a private repository for linux packages.

i.e.

`sudo apt-get install X`

where X is located in a private server only accessible to me and others with permissions?

If so, how would one go about doing this?

(Essentially X would just contain useful bash functions, my colleagues and I have developed)

Furthermore, can I `apt-get install` directly from github? E.g.

`sudo apt-get install git+https://github.com/X/Y.git` (something roughly along these lines)

Comment: I think you will find it in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line

Comment: @RamonSuarez That answer explains how to install using dpkg, not apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the desired packages on eg. a nsf. When this nfs is mounted somewhere on your computer you can simply install these packages with a command like:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file.deb
```

apt-get is simply a more advanced version for installing applications, it includes dependencies and downloads the needed files form the internet.

But maybe you are looking for something like this:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/keryx-offline-package-installation-made-easy-in-ubuntu
or this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal

Answer (score 1):

[You can specify password-protected APT repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18944407/1157100) using

```
deb https://username:password@repo.example.com/ubuntu …
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` files.